# Enable user to execute one command as another user

Tags: sudo, sudoedit

The goal is to let the `www-data` user execute `sudo -u postgres -H osm2pgsql [some options here]` without being asked for a password (as this will be part of a script wich runs automatically).

I thought I could do it with the following line in `sudoers` file

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u postgres -H osm2pgsql *
```

But this does not seem to work. 
 What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you need is

```
Defaults:www-data !requiretty
www-data ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/osm2pgsql
```

where `/usr/bin/osm2pgsql` should be replaced by the actual path of `osm2pgsql`. The `!requiretty` line allows the sudo from a script without a terminal.  This allows the command `sudo -u postgres -H osm2pgsql` with any options to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/osm2pgsql`